# Vector multiplication on a 2D array using Accelerate in Swift

Tags: swift, numpy, accelerate-framework

I have the following NumPy example which does element-wise vector multiplication on a 2D array:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[3, 5, 8, 7, 2],
              [1, 4, 9, 1, 3],
              [2, 7, 3, 1, 2],
              [5, 4, 9, 1, 6],
              [4, 2, 9, 6, 7]])

b = np.array([[2],
              [0.5],
              [9],
              [1],
              [18]])

c = a * b

print(c)
```

This prints the following:

```
[[  6.   10.   16.   14.    4. ]
 [  0.5   2.    4.5   0.5   1.5]
 [ 18.   63.   27.    9.   18. ]
 [  5.    4.    9.    1.    6. ]
 [ 72.   36.  162.  108.  126. ]]
```

I'm trying to do this calculation in Swift using Accelerate as shown below:

```swift
import Foundation
import Accelerate

let a: [Float] = [3, 5, 8, 7, 2,
                  1, 4, 9, 1, 3,
                  2, 7, 3, 1, 2,
                  5, 4, 9, 1, 6,
                  4, 2, 9, 6, 7]

let b: [Float] = [2,
                  0.5,
                  9,
                  1,
                  18]

var c: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 25)
vDSP_vmul(a, 1, b, 1, &c, 1, 25)

print(c)
```

The Swift code prints the following which is not correct:

```
[6.0, 2.5, 72.0, 7.0, 36.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.104904e-39, 4.7331654e-30, 3.7740115e-24, 6.737052e-37, 1.806498e-35, 1.19422e-39, 5.1722454e-26, 5.9787867e-25, 2.7286e-41, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.6543612e-24, 0.0, 0.0, 5.533857e-39, 3.73e-43]
```

Accelerate works with flatten arrays whereas NumPy supports 2D arrays. So I'm not sure how to multiply the 2D array with a vector in Accelerate. Is there a different Accelerate function that I should use for this type of multiplication?

Comment: Your code is attempting to multiply two 25-element long input vectors into a single 25-element long result vector (and hitting a buffer overrun of `b`, too). I don't see any specific accelerate functions to do this elementwise multiplication, I think you'll just need to do five separate `vDSP_vmul` calls (one for each row)

Answer (score 1):

To multiply this as a column, you need to use a stride. If you're taking the trouble to use Accelerate, then you probably also want to avoid extra allocations. You can use `Array(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:)` to fill in all the data like this:

```
let c = Array(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: a.count) { output, initializedCount in
    a.withUnsafeBufferPointer { abuffer in
        for i in b.indices {
            vDSP_vmul(abuffer.baseAddress! + i, b.count, // stride through a by the column size
                      b, 1,                              // stride one-by-one through b
                      output.baseAddress! + i, b.count,  // stride through the output by the column size
                      vDSP_Length(b.count))
        }
        initializedCount = abuffer.count
    }
}

// [6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 14.0, 4.0, 0.5, 2.0, 4.5, 0.5, 1.5, 18.0, 63.0, 27.0, 9.0, 18.0, 5.0, 4.0, 9.0, 1.0, 6.0, 72.0, 36.0, 162.0, 108.0, 126.0]
```

Comment: So there's no Accelerate function that takes in a 2D array and multiplies it by a column vector?

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the for-loop? Seems like that would kill performance for large arrays. Also, is there an approach that doesn't use unsafe pointers?

Comment: @wigging There are some newer Swift overlays you can play around with (e.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/3241034-multiply), which take any type that conforms to `AccelerateBuffer`. Notably, `UnsafeBufferPointer` conforms, but not `Array`. There's a bit of an assumption that if you're worried enough about performance that you're using Accelerate, you probably don't want to accidentally be causing allocations, CoW, etc., and that you're willing to drop to a lower level

Comment: "Is there a way to avoid the for-loop? Seems like that would kill performance for large arrays." Yeeeep. I don't see any more specific functions for this. One other solution idea is to find a fast way to expand out `[2, 0.5, 9, 1, 18]` into `[2, 2, 2, 2, , 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18]`, which you can then do a regular element-wise vector multiply with your matrix. I haven't found a fast way to do that, though.